# how to multiply dataframes elementwise and create multi-index -- Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication, multi-index

I have two DataFrames `date` and `supply`:

```
data =
    Nov_15   DEc_15   Jan_16
0    2        4        6
1    3        5        7

supply =
    c1    c2 
0   1     2     
1   3     4  
2   5     6
```

I want to multiply column `c1` of `supply` by row `0` of `date` elementwise, and column `c2` by row `1`. The result should be the following:

```
    Nov_15    Nov_15   Dec_15   Dec_15   Jan_16   Jan_16
    c1        c2       c1       c2       c1       c2
0   2         6        4        10       6        14
1   6         12       12       20       18       28
2   10        18       20       30       30       42
```

Can I write a function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reindex the two dataframes so their index/column match, and then multiply them:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame([[i*j for i in range(1, 3)] for j in range(2, 5)], index=list('abc'), columns=list('AB'))
print df1
df2 = pandas.DataFrame([[i*10**j for i in range(1, 4)] for j in range(1, 3)], columns=list('abc'))
print df2

df11 = df1.reindex(columns=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, df2.index]), level=0)
print df11
df22 = df2.T.reindex(columns=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, df2.index]), level=1)
print df22

df3 = df11.mul(df22)
print df3
```